# VS code - 2 split terminal in one (split)

Tags: visual-studio-code

As I'm working with Node.js and Angular, I've currently work with two terminals where I have to switch terminal by the dropdown option.

Is there a way to have two terminals (split) in the same place
like this:

[image]

Couldn't find a way.

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update - Visual studio code has this feature starting with version 1.21

> [Split terminals](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_split-terminals)
>
> The Integrated Terminal can now be split such that multiple are visible at once, which can enable much easier management of terminals when you need a watch and a run command for example:
>
> <sub>Open the article to see the [GIF](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_21/terminal-split.gif) demonstration.</sub>
>
> [image]
>
> Splitting can be done by clicking the split button in the panel, through the context menu or the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>.
>
> ....

---

## Before VS Code introduced the feature

### Inside vs code

You can configure your console to bash or cygwin, and then install and use [`tmux`](https://tmux.github.io/) or `screen`.

---

*Initial answer before I understood the question intent was to do it inside vs code*

### Outside vs code

#### On windows

I'm using [Cmder](http://cmder.net/).
It allows opening multiple cmd tabs, and configure more types of command lines / tabs - such as bash, nodejs etc.

[image: screen shot of side by side consoles in Cmder]

#### On Linux

I got to play a bit with [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) and I heard it's a good option.

Screen shot from google:
[image]

#### On Mac

As [Brad stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521755/vs-code-2-split-terminal-in-one-split/48522094?noredirect=1#comment92378294_48522094) - tmux works also on Macs, so have a look at the Linux section above.

Comment: I randomly stumbled upon this question while googling how to keep the split windows after VS code restarts.  Thanks for introducing me to Cmder!

Comment: @BradParks adding it to the answer :)

Comment: Is it possible to split two "JavaScript Debug Terminals"? When I open one and click split, it automatically splits to a ZSH.

Answer (score 3):

As of June 2021, you can select the terminal then enter command: `ctrl + shift + 5`.

Answer (score 2):

VSCode has added support to split the integrated terminal in february 2018, as requested by this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10546).

At the time it is not yet released, you need to install the Insiders version of VSCode.

You have to set the keybindings yourself, the default are still being discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7504#issuecomment-365683609).

Comment: As @Bilow said, support for splitting terminals has landed in v1.21 see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_integrated-terminal  Ctrl+\ or there is a button.