# how can I have 2 terminal monitor open at the same time (split) in vsc?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have 2 instances running in the picture.
I'd like to have them show up potentially together under the terminal tab if possible. (kinda like a terminal tab split screen --- instance1 on the left, instance2 on the right)

[image]

There're 2 games I want to get and the sale just ended.

I look up online, but none of psn price trackers is free, so I decide to monitor these 2 games myself.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS code - 2 split terminal in one (split)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521755/vs-code-2-split-terminal-in-one-split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console window, the add new terminal button (the `+` button) at the top right has a drop-down.

If you click on the drop-down (the `v` arrow) instead of the `+` you will see that there is an option to "split".

In the `split` submenu you can choose what terminal to run in the split window.

[image]